# Como implementar Plugins em um Framework MVC

Tags: php, mvc, plugin, framework

Estou criando meu próprio *[Framework MVC](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base)*, principalmente para estudos, e gostaria de implementar *plugins* nele, porém não faço a mínima ideia de como faze-lo.

Gostaria de saber alguns pontos, como:

**Controle de *plugins* instalados?**

Como controlar quais *plugins* estão instalados no Framework? Devo apenas pegar os arquivos do diretório de *plugins* e sair executando?

**Como, onde e quando executar o *script* do *plugin*?**

Quero saber como é o escopo de um plugin. Se ele seria uma classe que eu deveria instanciar em alguma propriedade do *Controller*, ou se não devo executar nada, e o desenvolvedor que estiver utilizando o *framework* deve se preocupar com isso?

**O que encapsular e o que permitir ao plugin?**

Preciso me preocupar com o plugin com o que o plugin tem acesso. Por exemplo, a conexão com o banco de dados seria um atributo padrão que o plugin teria acesso. Mas devo me preocupar com algo mais, como *models* e etc?

**Existe algum padrão para plugins no MVC?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caro KaduAmara,

Implemente igual o [Laravel](http://laravel.com), pelo [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) tendo em seu projeto uma ***pasta*** `vendor`. Todos os pacotes são instalados (copiados) para essa pasta adicionando na chave `require` do seu `composer.json` e após o comando do `composer update`.

***Exemplo básico do arquivo*** `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "stackoverflow/packages",
    "description": "Packages",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "stackoverflow",
            "email": "stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {}
}
```

Dentro dessa pasta tem um `autoload.php`, faça a referencia com [include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php)/[require](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require.php) no seu projeto [Framework MVC](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base), e funcionará os pacotes para o seu projeto.

**Dica:** faça uma instalação do Laravel em seu computador e no [repositório de pacotes](https://packagist.org/) ([Packagist - The PHP Package Repository](https://packagist.org/)), instale alguns pacotes e observe o procedimento.

***Edição***

***1) Controle de plugins instalados?***

Com o gerenciador [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) e seu arquivo de configuração `composer.json` você tem o controle daquilo que foi instalado em sua aplicação, inclusive com versionamento e melhorias no pacote (plugin) instalado.

*Exemplo:* para instalar o pacote [fuel/email](https://packagist.org/packages/fuel/email) adicione no seu arquivo de configuração `composer.json` na chave `require` **"fuel/email"** da *versão* `1.8` aonde seu sistema principal [Framework MVC](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base) utilize quando for necessário. Observe a configuração:

```
{
    "name": "stackoverflow/packages",
    "description": "Packages",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "stackoverflow",
            "email": "stackoverflow@stackoverflow.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
           "fuel/email":"1.8.*"
    }
}
```

Após essa configuração o digite no prompt de comando (console) `php.exe composer.phar update` esse comando instala o pacote na sua aplicação em um pasta chamada **vendor** (padrão).

***Observação:*** para desinstalar o pacote é só remover da chave `require` o nome do pacote e rodar no prompt de comando (console) `php.exe composer.phar update` novamente.

***2) Como, onde e quando executar o script do plugin?***

A partir da configuração e instalação do item **1)** o plugin está disponível no seu sistema. A execução e controle é feito pelo desenvolvedor que vai utilizar da melhor maneira possível, ou seja, quem determina que momento vai utilizar é o próprio desenvolvedor que está utilizando o seu [Framework MVC](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/Base).

*Exemplo:* Quero utilizar o pacote instalado no item **1)**, então:

```
$mail = Email::forge();
$mail->from('me@domain.com', 'Your Name Here');
$mail->to('mail@domain.com');
$mail->to('mail@domain.com', 'His/Her Name');
$email->body('My email body');
$email->html_body(\View::forge('email/template', $email_data));
$email->alt_body('This is my alt body, for non-html viewers.');
$email->subject('This is the subject');
$email->priority(\Email::P_HIGH);
$result = $email->send();
```

O autor do pacote coloca no seu [github](https://github.com/) o modo de utilização do pacote, a explicação está no [link](https://github.com/fuel/email).

***3) O que encapsular e o que permitir ao plugin?***

O pacote instalado tem acesso ao seu sistema mediante a intervenção do programador, isso não é razão de acesso e sim de usar, pegar algo que já está pronto e adicionar como funcionalidade no seu sistema. No item **2)** fica claro que o pacote de e-mail instalado para envio de mensagens só é acionado quando o desenvolvedor instânciar a sua `classe`.

***4) Existe algum padrão para plugins no MVC?***

Existe, no exemplo dado pelo [Packagist](https://packagist.org/), segue um padrão aonde suas instalações são feitas a partir da configuração de um arquivo no formato [json](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (`composer.json`) e quando o `composer` tem a responsabilidade de gerenciar. No próprio site tem a explicação de como se cria pacotes para que no seu `autoload.php`, seja registrado o pacote e sua aplicação tenha acesso.

***Leitura:***

[Dependency Manager for PHP](https://getcomposer.org/)

[Book Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/)

[laravel.com](http://laravel.com)

Comment: João obrigado pela resposta, mas ela não está respondendo a(s) outra(s) pergunta(s), `O que encapsular e o que permitir ao plugin?` e `Como, onde e quando executar o script do plugin?`. Não sei se fui muito claro... Se quiser posso melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: KaduAmaral, eu passei a você um gerenciador de pacotes (que podem ser uma extensão da sua aplicação). O plugin ou pacote ou `helper` são feitos com um determinado fim diante de um core de aplicação. É assim que muitos framework PHP funcionam e nele você desenvolve uma infinidades de sub sistemas dentro do sistema maior. Vê se você me entende o plugin que você instala na sua aplicação é assim: são código direcionado para um determinado fim que auxilia o principal nas tarefas. Exemplo: um plugin para envio de e-mail, um form de login e senha do usuário, tudo se pode fazer com esse gerenciador

Comment: Vou editar a minha resposta e tentar direcionar ao máximo para que você entenda o que significa gerenciar pacotes de aplicação.

Comment: Valeu João, fico no aguardo. Se tu puder fazer um exemplo simples, como o do envio de e-mails.

Comment: Uma coisa que eu observei no seu caso, você está confundido acesso com pacote/plugin. Pacote/Plugin são mini sistemas que são agregados no sistema maior que no seu caso é `Framework MVC`. O padrão é feito por você, mas, esse gerenciador (composer) é o atual utilizado em diversos frameworks MVC com Laravel, Lumen, Slim, etc. Entra nesse link do http://www.slimframework.com/ olha como ele é instaldo. o seja até os sitemas maiores já são gerenciador pelo composer.

Comment: Qualquer coisa pode perguntar!

Comment: Respondeu minhas dúvidas. Obrigado.